# Generating XML based on condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to generate XML based on condition. I am getting the XML output from Database, but i want to display the nodes in such a manner based on the ID.

If id of the elements are same, they should come under one node.

Comment: Perhaps an example? What is the XML, what would be an example ID, where does it come from...? What should be the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out PHP's [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml)? It enables you to perform XPath queries on XML data

Answer (score 0):

you can handle an xml in many ways and yes you can group the xml items per db id.

imho your question needs more details:
how do you get the xml?
how do you query the database?